# Use score() after predict() in sklearn without recalculating

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

**Context**

I use `sklearn` machine learning algorithms like `SVR` for a regression-task.

```py
from sklearn.svm import SVR
model = SVR(kernel='poly', degree=2, epsilon=.5)
model.fit(
      features # Numpy array with features
    , target   # Numpy array with the target
)
```

Afterwards I return the score of the regression using the `.score()`-function.
Additionally, I need the prediction-results using `.predict()` for further processing.

```py
some_data = [...] # Numpy array with some data to predict
correct_targets = [...] # Numpy array with targets according to some data

# Get R²
print("R²:", model.score(
      some_data
    , correct_targets
))
# Store prediction
pred = model.predict(some_data)
```

**Question**

When I run the code in the above version the model is calculated twice - once for `.score()` and once for `.predict()`.
However, I cannot run the `.score()` on the saved `.predict()`.
This is a bit nasty since the calculation takes some time.

Is it possible to store the prediction and apply `.score()` afterwards without recalculating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the predicted values:

```
pred = model.predict(some_data)
```

and the respective ground truth `correct_targets`, it is straightforward to get the R^2 score without re-running the model, as scikit-learn has a [dedicated function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html) for this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

r2_score(correct_targets, pred)
```